# Не могу декомпилить Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Мне нужно декомпилировать forge 1.7.10 чтобы убрать кнопки добавления сервера и в целом переделать всё меню. Я скачал MCP 9.04, открыл decompile.bat, после открыл тут Eclipse, но везде выдает ошибки, src пустой. Что делать не понимаю, помогите пожалуйста :(
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в папке jars у вас есть что то? насколько я знаю там должен лежать клиент и сервер майнкрафта. если установлен, то скорее всего у вас библиотек нету

Comment: еще есть предположение что вы не активировали install.cmd который лежит в папке forge

Comment: Папки forge у меня нету, в jars у меня папки assets, libraries и versions.

Comment: Я скачал srс forge 1.7.10 с minecraftforge net.

Comment: ну так в архиве с src forge есть папка forge её кинуть(не содержимое, а её) кинуть в корень mcp, открыть, и активировать install.cmd который там лежит, и ты возможно получишь ошибку изза scala-library, просто скачай в инете и положи в папку с библиотекой

Comment: В архиве есть папки eclipse, gradle и src, файлы build.gradle, gradlew, gradlew.bat и текстовики с лицензиями. Нужно создать папку в mcp под названием forge и вот это содержимое туда скинуть?

Comment: погодите, ща гляну

Comment: я сейчас глянул, там надо по другому, я думал надо как в 1.5.2, вот держите статью по созданию там описано, да и там mcp не нужен https://minecraft-ru.gamepedia.com/Создание_модификаций_с_помощью_Forge/1.7%2B

Comment: Спасибо большое!